# No re-evaluation of remember in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I need to control the visibility of "save" button on my "settings" screen:

```
val enableSaveButton = remember(
    modifiedUser,
    originalUser,
    changePasswordData,
    modifiedExtraSettingsData,
    originalExtraSettingsData,
) {
    val userModifications = if (isLoggedIn) {
        modifiedUser.value != originalUser.value
    } else {
        false
    }
    val passwordModifications = changePasswordData.value != ChangePasswordData.NULL_OBJECT
    val isPasswordDataConsistent = if (isLoggedIn && passwordModifications) {
        changePasswordData.value.isValidData()
    } else {
        true
    }
    val extraModifications = modifiedExtraSettingsData.value != originalExtraSettingsData.value
    (userModifications || extraModifications || passwordModifications) && isPasswordDataConsistent
}
```

My problem is that this `remember` block is not re-evaluated when `changePasswordData` mutable state changes. It does re-evaluate when `modifiedExtraSettingsData` changes, however.
I used breakpoints in the code to verify that `changePasswordData` is indeed changed and that change triggers re-composition of the respective Composables, but not re-evaluation of the above expression.
As far as I can tell, I use the same approach for `changePasswordData` and `modifiedExtraSettings`, yet get different behavior.

These are the declarations of the respective mutable states:

```
    private val originalUser = mutableStateOf(User.NULL_USER)
    private val modifiedUser = mutableStateOf(User.NULL_USER)

    private val changePasswordData = mutableStateOf(ChangePasswordData.NULL_OBJECT)

    private val originalExtraSettingsData = mutableStateOf(ExtraSettingsData.NULL_OBJECT)
    private val modifiedExtraSettingsData = mutableStateOf(ExtraSettingsData.NULL_OBJECT)
```

And that's how I mutate `changePasswordData` and `modifiedExtraSettings`:

```
MyTextField(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    text = changePasswordData.value.currentPassword,
    label = stringResource(id = R.string.settings_current_password),
    enabled = true,
    visualTransformation = PasswordVisualTransformation(),
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password, imeAction = ImeAction.Next),
    onValueChanged = {
        changePasswordData.value = changePasswordData.value.copy(
            currentPassword = it
        )
    }
)

MyTextField(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.5f),
    label = stringResource(id = R.string.settings_server_base_url_label),
    text = extraSettingsData.value.baseServerUrl,
    onValueChanged = {
        extraSettingsData.value = extraSettingsData.value.copy(
            baseServerUrl = it
        )
    }
)
```

So, why the difference in behavior?

Answer (score 2):

After spending another 30 mins on this, I figured out that I had to use the values of mutable states as keys, rather than the states themselves:

```
val enableSaveButton = remember(
    modifiedUser.value,
    originalUser.value,
    changePasswordData.value,
    modifiedExtraSettingsData.value,
    originalExtraSettingsData.value,
) {
    val userModifications = if (isLoggedIn) {
        modifiedUser.value != originalUser.value
    } else {
        false
    }
    val passwordModifications = changePasswordData.value != ChangePasswordData.NULL_OBJECT
    val isPasswordDataConsistent = if (isLoggedIn && passwordModifications) {
        changePasswordData.value.isValidData()
    } else {
        true
    }
    val extraModifications = modifiedExtraSettingsData.value != originalExtraSettingsData.value
    (userModifications || extraModifications || passwordModifications) && isPasswordDataConsistent
}
```

It's very odd that the wrong approach worked for some of the mutable states, but not others.

Comment: It makes sense if you think about it, since the state object doesn't change, so the block doesn't get triggered.

Also, Compose doesn't generally like mixing its api with other implementations. What I mean by this is that I'd expect your state declarations to be:

`private var changePasswordData by remember { mutableStateOf(ChangePasswordData.NULL_OBJECT) }`. Otherwise, you risk recreating those objects for every recomposition.

Comment: What @eydryan says is correct, and while it's a matter of preference, I always prefer using `by` delegates whenever possible, since they make the code less verbose than having to call `.value` every time.